# Ember link-to handlebars and jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, ember.js, datatables, handlebars.js

I have an Ember View that sets up jQuery Datatables when given a set of columns and a datasource.  In my case, this datasource is from Ember Data.

I use this for an admin panel, so I'll list some rows from the model and then I'll allow admins to perform actions on these items.  Actions could include an 'Edit' link or maybe a 'Delete' link, etc.

Right now, I use the Datatable's `mRender` functionality to create a link to the appropriate page.  This works just fine, but forces a browser refresh which is a little annoying.  I'd like to use Ember's `link-to` functionality instead.

I tried something like this:

`Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#link-to "modelName", ' + full.id + '}}Edit{{/link-to}}');`

However, compile will return a javascript function instead of straight html text.  Can anyone give me some advice or code snippet to help achieve this functionality?

Here's a JSBin mimicking my current schema: [JSBin Example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aCAWIku/4/edit?js,output)

**Update**

I am using `location: 'history'` in the router instead of the traditional hash urls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{{link-to}}` helper can be used within a template, but since you specify the HTML via `mRender`, it is possible to add a hashtag to the href built and an appropriate route. In this case there will be no page refresh.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uYeXixiw/1/edit

**js**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('details',{path:'user/:user_id'});
});

var data = [
      { 'id': 1, 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Dale' },
      { 'id': 2, 'firstName': 'Yehuda', 'lastName': 'Katz' },
      { 'id': 3, 'firstName': 'Peter', 'lastName': 'Wagenet' }
    ];

App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

model:function(params){
return data[params.user_id-1];
}
});



App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    var columns = [
      { "sClass": "item", "mData": "firstName" },
      { "sClass": "item", "mData": "lastName" },
      { "sClass": "item", "mData": null, "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
          return '<a href="#/user/' + full.id + '/">View Details</a>';
        }
      }
    ];
    controller.set('columns', columns);
  },
  model: function() {
    return data;
  }
});

App.DataTableView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName:'table',
  columnsBinding: 'controller.columns',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    var value = this.get('value');
    var data = null;
    if(value === null || value === undefined) {
      console.log('Value is null');
      data = [];
    } else {
      console.log('Got Value: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
      data = value;//value.getEach('data'); //for Ember Data
      var items = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    var columns = this.get('columns');
    this.$().dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "aaData": data,
      "aoColumns": columns,
      "sEmptyTable": "Loading data from server"
    });
  },
  onValueChanged: function() {
    var self = this;
    var value = this.get('value');
    var data = null;
    if(value === null || value === undefined) {
      console.log('Value is null');
      data = [];
    } else {
      console.log('Got Value: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
      data = value;//value.getEach('data'); //for Ember Data
    }
    var columns = this.get('columns');
    this.$().dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "aaData": data,
      "aoColumns": columns,
      "sEmptyTable": "Loading data from server"
    });
    return;
  }.observes('value')
});
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{view App.DataTableView valueBinding="model" columnsBinding="columns"}}
  </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="details">
    <h2>details</h2>

    {{controller.firstName}}
<br/>
{{#link-to 'index'}}back{{/link-to}}
  </script>
```

**EDIT**  - response to comments - support for history location

I have noticed that sometimes it is required to access `ember` entities from the DOM using pure js. This can occur in cases where another js framework related to `UI` is difficut to be adopted to the `templating` system of `ember`. It is really interesting being able to achieve this in an easy manner, without ruining the good design of your system and the separtion of concerns.

So in your case, since it is not possible to use `handlebars` helpers e.g. `{{link-to}}`, `{{action}}`, to an already rendered template it is possible to call ember entities from DOM events.

a generic function returning a view passing a DOM element

```
function getView($el){
  return Ember.View.views[$el.closest(".ember-view").attr("id")];
}
```

used in `mRender` as,

```
 ....
return '<a href=# onclick="getView($(this)).get(\'controller\').send(\'showDetails\',' + full.id + ')">View Details</a>';
```

### http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UnUdUpO/1

*(the paths setup is a little weird due to jsbin, but you get the idea)*

Also as noted within jsbin if `<a>` tags are used, then `preventDefault` (i.e. in view's `didInsertElement` callback) is required for the transitions to work.

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'history'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('index', {path: '/UnUdUpO/1' }); //For jsbin
  this.route('details',{ path:'/UnUdUpO/1/user/:user_id' });
});

var data = [
  { 'id': 1, 'firstName': 'Tom', 'lastName': 'Dale' },
  { 'id': 2, 'firstName': 'Yehuda', 'lastName': 'Katz' },
  { 'id': 3, 'firstName': 'Peter', 'lastName': 'Wagenet' }
];

function getView($el){
  return Ember.View.views[$el.closest(".ember-view").attr("id")];
}


App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model:function(params){
    return data[params.user_id-1];
  }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    var columns = [
      { "sClass": "item", "mData": "firstName" },
      { "sClass": "item", "mData": "lastName" },
      { "sClass": "item", "mData": null, "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
        //if using an <a> tag element for ember transition, then preventDefault is required
          return '<a href=# onclick="getView($(this)).get(\'controller\').send(\'showDetails\',' + full.id + ')">View Details</a>';
        /*return '<button onclick="getView($(this)).get(\'controller\').send(\'showDetails\',' + full.id + ')" >details</button>';*/
        }
      }
    ];
    controller.set('columns', columns);
  },
  model: function() {
    return data;
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions:{
    showDetails:function(userId){
      this.transitionToRoute('details',userId);
    }
  }
});

App.DataTableView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName:'table',
  columnsBinding: 'controller.columns',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var self = this;
    var value = this.get('value');
    var data = null;
    if(value === null || value === undefined) {
      console.log('Value is null');
      data = [];
    } else {
      console.log('Got Value: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
      data = value;//value.getEach('data'); //for Ember Data
      var items = JSON.stringify(data);
    }

    var columns = this.get('columns');
    this.$().dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "aaData": data,
      "aoColumns": columns,
      "sEmptyTable": "Loading data from server"
    });

    //this line is required for links used to make an ember transition
    this.$('a').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});

  },
  onValueChanged: function() {
    var self = this;
    var value = this.get('value');
    var data = null;
    if(value === null || value === undefined) {
      console.log('Value is null');
      data = [];
    } else {
      console.log('Got Value: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
      data = value;//value.getEach('data'); //for Ember Data
    }
    var columns = this.get('columns');
    this.$().dataTable( {
      "bJQueryUI": true,
      "aaData": data,
      "aoColumns": columns,
      "sEmptyTable": "Loading data from server"
    });
    return;
  }.observes('value')
});
```

**hsb**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{view App.DataTableView valueBinding="model" columnsBinding="columns"}}
  </script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="details">
    <h2>details</h2>

    {{controller.firstName}}
<br/>
{{#link-to 'index'}}back{{/link-to}}
  </script>
```

Comment: That works great using the default router.  I forgot to mention, I'm using the history location feature of the router.  Apparently this breaks the hash schema.  I updated your example with the location: history feature enabled: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uYeXixiw/3/edit?js,output

Comment: @holtkampw updated the answer taking into account this requirement